# Sine Wave With Alternating Wavelength

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, wave-equation, constants

**Please Read Everything Fully and Carefully Before Responding!!**

I'm trying to formulate parametric equations for a sine wave where the wavelength grows by a constant on alternate sides, in this case, 1.3, and where  the amplitude decreases in an inverse manner. (See my image. It MUST be noted that the image probably does NOT look like the actual, properly graphed wave will!)[image]

To give you an idea of the sort of equations i'm looking for:

$$y(t)=(function)$$
$$x(t)=sin(t)(function)^{-1}$$

**NOTE. I'm using the term 'wavelength' in a way that is, to my understanding not in conformity with the standard definition. But, the above image should clarify what I'm talking about satisfactorily.**

**NOTE. A note to everyone: I'd rather deal with this problem in the form that is given by my example equations, unless there is some issue with doing so...**

Comment: I'd suggest a function of the form $f(x)\sin g(x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar, yes, they ought to grow/shrink in step and in inverse. (See the example equations.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, thank you for the input. Can you elaborate?

Comment: $x=1.3^t,y=1.3^{-t}\sin\pi t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lovely function $y = f(x)$ which is simply turned into a parametric equation by defining it as $\langle t, f(t) \rangle$.

Therefore, $$y = \cos\left(\pi\left(\frac{\ln\Big(\big(x+\frac1{r+1}\big)(r^2-1)+1\Big)}{\ln r}\right)\right)$$

For your case, $r=1.3$.

This function matches the above graph, where it starts at $(0,-1)$. If you prefer a different starting location, please drop a comment and I'll be back with an improved answer!

$$y = \cos\left(\pi\left(\frac{\ln\Big(\big(x+\frac{r^{(n)}-1}{r^-1}\big)(r^2-1)+1\Big)}{\ln r}\right)\right)$$
See the tiny $n$ in the exponent? Mess with that, and you have phase shift. You can also drop a negative in front of the cosine, or change it to sine, or etc. Just to preempt any questions.

Alrighty!

$$\langle\frac{r^{2t}-r^{n}}{r^{2}-1},r^{\left(\frac{r^{2t}-r^{n}}{r^{2}-1}\right)}\cos\left(2\pi t\right)\rangle$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I love your function. It is indeed absolutely beautiful! I want to accept it as the answer. I will if you're willing to post something that will make it correspond to this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wwqngyymh4 for $$x(t)$$

By this I mean, I want the wave's height to decrease to the same degree that its wavelength increases. A good way of thinking about this is that the answer will fit on a hyperbolic type shape. 

Thank you again so much!

Comment: See this link for what I mean with the hyperbolic shape:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/notnadmsbf

Comment: A note: My intuition has lead me to think that this will be easier to work on parametrically.

Comment: @JinnyEcckle Sorry it took me so long to get back on this. The relevant formulas and parameters are here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mi3sauwzvn. There is a parametric way to do this (from which you can see my method for solving the problem: geometric series!) but it doesn't seem to be any neater than the original. Especially when you throw in amplitude. Nonetheless, enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! Brilliant work!